# Include_once not working in wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am trying to include file from another folder to wordpress page
but did not get output please help me and give proper solution for that queries.

```
<?php
/**
 * Emily::Responsive WordPress Theme for Webhost    
 * Copyright © 2013 Nextinspire.com. All Rights Reserved
 */
?>

<div id="home-widgets">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block1">
            <div class="FL">Register Your Domain Name</div>
            <div class="FR"><a href="/shop/domainchecker.php?search=bulkregister">Bulk Domain Search</a> | <a href="/domain/price-list-for-other-extensions/">Domain Price List</a></div>
        </di>
         <div class="block2">
                <div class="">
                    <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'domainchecker', '[whmcs-connect get=domainchecker label="'.__('Register', 'emily').'"]' ); ?>
                </div>
                <span class="wtxt">Search Domain</span>
            </div>
        <div class="block3">
        <img src="http://demo1.qualispace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/in.png"><?php include_once("http://demo.qualispace.com/shop/feeds/domain_price1.php");  ?>Start from $6.99 <img src="http://demo1.qualispace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/com.png">Start from $8.99 <img src="http://demo1.qualispace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/org.png">Start from $8.99
        </div>
   </div>
</div><!--/#home-widgets-->
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(include_once("http://demo.qualispace.com/shop/feeds/domain_price1.php");` returns ?

Answer (score 0):

The end tag to `<div class="block1"/>` appears to have a typo.  Try `</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `domain_price1.php` contain a variable? if yes then include your `index` in the top of your file and then just echo out the variable.